# Right angled median intersection question

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: Find the length AB]

All the information is included in the image. Find the length AB.

Only clue I have is that the length CX is 2.5 where X is the perpendicular foot of B which i found out geometrically. However I don't know how to find CX mathematically.

Comment: See http://www.qbyte.org/puzzles/p100s.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G is center of gravity, let $ BG= 2y,AG=2x$ where $G$ divides meridian in ratio $2:1$
We can use Pythagoras thm to find hypotenuses
$$ x^2 + 4 y^2= \frac94, \quad 4 x^2 + y^2=4$$ 
To solve the two equations treat $x^2,y^2$ as whole entities making them linear. 
$$ x^2= \frac{11}{12} , y^2=\frac13; \quad AB^2=4( \frac13+\frac{11}{12}) \rightarrow AB= \sqrt5.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using Pythagoras' theorem and basic facts about medians will be enough: set $AA'=3a$, $BB'=3b$ and let $G$ be the inersection of $(AA')$  and $(BB')$. As $AG=2a$, $BG=2b$,  Pythagoras in the right triangles $AGB', A'GB$ and $AGB$ says that
$$4a^2+b^2=4, \quad a^2+4b^2=\frac 94, \quad AB^2=4(a^2+b^2)$$
Adding the first two equations  we have $\,5(a^2+b^2)=\dfrac{25}4 $, whence
$$AB^2=5\enspace\text{or}\enspace AB=\sqrt 5.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is a well known problem that says that if two medians are perpendicular then $ a^2+b^2=5 c^2 $ or something like that. The proof uses the formula for the length of the median, the fact that medians cut each other in a 2:1 ratio, the Pythagorean theorem then some expansion etc.